# How To make dropdown content stay open when mouse moves away from trigger element

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

So there are three buttons in a row and when one is hovered on, it opens up dropdown content that goes under all three buttons as seen in the pic.  However, when the mouse moves down to the content it disappears.
Can't Post Image inside yet **
[image]
[image]

Tried moving dropdown content into the same divs, but then I can't make the content take up the whole bottom space. I probably need to reconstruct everything 
Sorry if the question doesn't make sense

```js
class DropDown {
  constructor() {
    // Cards 
    this.serveCard = $('#serve-card');
    this.protectCard = $('.protect-card');
    this.commercialCard = $('#commercial-card');
    // DropDown Area for Cards
    this.dropServe = $('#serve-card-dropdown');
    this.dropProtect = $('#protect-card-dropdown');
    this.dropCommercial = $('#commercial-card-dropdown');


    // Drop Down Container 

    this.dropDownContainer = $('#drop_down_container');
    this.events();

  }
  events() {

    this.protectCard.hover(this.dropDownIn.bind(this.dropProtect),
      this.dropDownOut.bind(this.dropProtect));

    this.serveCard.hover(this.dropDownIn.bind(this.dropServe),
      this.dropDownOut.bind(this.dropServe).bind(this));

    this.commercialCard.hover(this.dropDownIn.bind(this.dropCommercial),
      this.dropDownOut.bind(this.dropCommercial));


    // Style Cards On Hover

    this.protectCard.hover(this.styleCard.bind(this.protectCard),
      this.styleCard.bind(this.protectCard));

    this.serveCard.hover(this.styleCard.bind(this.serveCard),
      this.styleCard.bind(this.serveCard));

    this.commercialCard.hover(this.styleCard.bind(this.commercialCard),
      this.styleCard.bind(this.commercialCard));
  }

  dropDownIn() {
    this.removeClass('inactive');
  }
  dropDownOut() {

    this.addClass('inactive');
  }

  styleCard() {
    this.toggleClass('inactive');
  }

}
```

```css
/* Drop down Menu --------- */

.blue_card {
  border: 2px solid white;
  margin: 0px 1% 0 1%;
  padding-top: 25px;
  background-color: rgb(0, 119, 204);
  color: white;
  border-bottom: none;
}

.blue_card.inactive {
  background-color: rgba(88, 128, 155, 0.424);
  border-bottom: none;
}

.drop-down-cont {
  position: relative;
}

.drop-down {
  background-color: rgb(0, 119, 204);
  margin-right: 10px;
  margin-left: 1%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  height: 100px;
  width: 98%;
  transition: height 500ms;
  border-right: 2px solid white;
  border-left: 2px solid white;
  border-top: 2px solid white;
  border-bottom: 2px solid white;
  color: white;
}

.drop-down.inactive {
  height: 0;
  transition: height 500ms;
  font-size: 0;
  border-bottom: none;
  border-top: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="row blue-card-cont">
  <div id='protect-card' class="protect-card col blue_card inactive">
    <h5>PROTECT</h5>
    <p>PROTECT WITH COPYRIGHT</p>
  </div>
  <div id='serve-card' class="col blue_card inactive">
    <h5>SERVE</h5>
    <p>PROTECT DATA ENTRY. KILL THREATS</p>
  </div>

  <div id='commercial-card' class="col blue_card inactive">
    <h5>COMMERCIALISE</h5>
    <p>CREATE NEW BUSINESS</p>
  </div>

</div>
<div id='#drop_down_container' class="drop-down-cont">
  <div id='protect-card-dropdown' class="drop-down inactive">
    <p>Protect</p>
  </div>
  <div id='serve-card-dropdown' class="drop-down inactive">
    <p>Serve</p>
  </div>
  <div id='commercial-card-dropdown' class="drop-down inactive">
    <p>Commercial</p>
  </div>

</div>
```

Comment: please add working example of your problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use simple css dropdowns like this one [Solved with CSS! Dropdown Menus](https://css-tricks.com/solved-with-css-dropdown-menus/)